# .sh file to count number of files

Tags: bash, scripts

Friends,

I have a small basic shell script that zips files in directory and sub directory.  However, I need to add a counter to only zip a certain number of files )eg. 50 files.  I am unable to accomplish please advise.  Please find my script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=/home/tmp
cd "${BASEDIR}"
pwd

for i in `find .  -name *.jpg -type f -print -mtime +30`
do
  zip ${i%.*} $i
  echo "Process Completed"
done
```

Please advise?  Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

There's couple things to address:

- don't use backticks; `$(...)` is generally preferred nowadays especially since they handle nested quoting. Not a problem here, but be aware of that
- `find` should be used in conjunction with `while` loop for complex processing of filenames. While loop also helps imitate C-style for loop, and in fact it's a common notion in programming that you can implement same behavior in either loop.
- use `-u` flag for update, as `zip -u zipfile.zip` "$current_file", if you're adding to existing zip file

Thus your script is better written as

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# using capitals for variable names
# can be confusing and interfere with env
# or shell variables
basedir=/home/tmp
cd "${basedir}"
# You can use variable instead of pwd command
printf "Current working directory:%s\n" "$PWD"

counter=0    
# pipelines can be broken to multiple lines
find .  -name '*.jpg' -type f -print0 -mtime +30 |
while IFS= read -r f_name; do
    counter=$((counter+1))
    zip u ${i%.*} "$f_name"
    # This is where you check for number of files processed
    if [ "$counter" -eq 50 ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

---

If that's too verbose and lengthy, we can have a little fun with `find` and `-exec` flag, but the problem is that we can't have a shared variable between `-exec` calls. There fore we can make use of a temp file. We also need to somehow stop `find` from calling our `-exec` process over all files greater than limit, so we can kill parent process of the shell specified by `$PPID` variable.

```
cd "$basedir"
find -type f -name '*.jpg' -mtime +30  -exec bash -c '
    f=/tmp/zip.counter; 
    [ -e "$f" ] && c=$(cat /tmp/zip.counter);
    c=$((c+1));
    [ "$c" -ge 50 ] && kill $(awk "/^Pid:/ {print $2}");
    zip u ${i%.*} "$1";
    echo "$c" > "$f"' sh {} \; && rm /tmp/zip.counter
```

Of course, this solution is not very practical and arguably less readable than the one with `while` loop. This bit is just for fun.

Comment: Thank you so much Sergyl.  You explained things so well and I am very grateful as I learned a few things from you.  I think the first option does sound better and I will work on that approach.

Comment: I ran the first script and I got the following errors:  ./archivefiles.sh: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @FeminaJaffer Ah, yes, there's a stray backquote at `+30 `in the find command. Remove that